# How to upload my GWT website

Tags: java, web-applications

I am new in web development , i have developed a small app in GWT , now i want it to be Online for free
what are the steps for that , where to get domain ,upload my files etc .

Comment: Sorry. Could you be more specific? you want to deploy your application to the website ? also you dont have any java hosting ?

Comment: yes, i want my application to be on website, i don't have any java hosting , how to get that..

Comment: option 1: run on your server, set domain names point to your server; option 2: buy dedicated server/java hosting. 

To buy domain name - this is another topic to discuss. for example you can buy it at godaddy.com, etc...
To try java hosting you can look at jelastic.com

Your question has nothing related to GWT.

Comment: One more clarification: If you compile GWT code only in client code - you don't need java hosting. Otherwise you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're developing your GWT app in Eclipse with Google plugin - the easiest way for you would be deployment to appengine. It's free Java hosting and it would serve your need for static hosting.

http://code.google.com/appengine/

There would be some configuration overhead, but if you start with generating Appengine project in eclipse with GWT. You get pritty nice configuration from the start.

You can ommit everything about java in the documentation.